# django distinct doesn't return just unique fields

Tags: django, django-views, distinct

I've a models for chat messages with three fields:

sender, recipient ( ForeignKey for User model ) and message as a TextField.

I'm trying to select all unique conversations with either sender either recipient field (exclude request.user). And I'm a bit messed in how to implement that.

I've 2 issues:

```
Message.objects.filter(Q(sender = request.user)|Q(recipient = request.user)).values('sender').distinct()
```

doesn't return a list of unique records ( even with order_by ). I've a lot absolutely the same senders: `{'sender': 4L}, {'sender': 4L}` (the same is with recipients).

And the second issue is:

Do I need to concatenate two queysets (for senders and recipients) or there is another way to get the whole list of conversations for current request.user?

upd. ok, here it is table content:

```
mysql> select id, sender_id, recipient_id, body from messages_message ;
+----+-----------+--------------+-----------+
| id | sender_id | recipient_id | body      |
+----+-----------+--------------+-----------+
|  1 |         4 |            1 | Message 1 |
|  2 |         4 |            1 | Message 2 |
+----+-----------+--------------+-----------+
```

and here it is result of

```
Message.objects.filter(Q(sender = request.user)|Q(recipient = request.user)).values('sender').distinct()

[{'sender': 4L}, {'sender': 4L}]
```

But I expected to get just a `[{'sender': 4L}]`.

So, what's wrong?

upd2. my model:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField(_("Body"))
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sent_messages', verbose_name=_("Sender"))
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='received_messages', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Recipient"))
    sent_at = models.DateTimeField(_("sent at"), null=True, blank=True)
```

I need to select all conversation partners (people who sent or received message to request.user) of current user.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have unique records there? They may have the same sender, but different pks. It looks to me like your query will give you what you ask in the second part of your question.

Comment: @RobL I've updated the question. It's not clear from your comment, does distinct always return unique by pk? I thought it will return the unique based on field in values().

Comment: That's not what DISTINCT does. Distinct returns unique rows, and that's what it's doing here. Since each of those is a unique message, it gets returned. DISTINCT would come in to play if you had a JOIN clause that was causing multiple rows to be returned, but they were really referencing the same parent row. You may be wanting to use GROUP_BY. But be careful, it's often a performance killer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you really want to get back, but if you want distinct Senders, then you should select from that table instead. If we could see your models (from Models.py) then it would be easier to help you solve.

Comment: @RobL I need a kind of `sort|uniq` operation in django on certain field. Models are in question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just my $.02, I really think that this sort of logic is handled better by python than SQL. If you use query params that are specific to one DB, then it kind of defeats the purpose of the ORM, in my opinion.

I would try something like this:

```
messages = Message.objects.filter(Q(sender = request.user)|Q(recipient = request.user))
## Does this need to be 'Q'? ##
```

Then:

```
partners = set()
for m in messages:
    partners.add(m.sender)
    partners.add(m.recipient)
```

If you were going to look at this set often, you could cache it.

But it *might* be better to make `partners` a field of `User`, and add to it every time a message is sent. Then no complex query would ever need to be made, just a simple `User.partners`.

I assume that you need to get the `User` object to send a message anyway, so it shouldn't be extra overhead.

Answer (score 1):

As Rob pointed out, `distinct()` works differently than you expected. It looks at *all* the fields to determine uniqueness, not just the ones you specify in `values()`.

If you're using PostgreSQL then you can do what you want by passing arguments to `distinct()`. From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#distinct):

> You can pass positional arguments (*fields) in order to specify the
>   names of fields to which the DISTINCT should apply. This translates to
>   a SELECT DISTINCT ON SQL query. Here’s the difference. For a normal
>   distinct() call, the database compares each field in each row when
>   determining which rows are distinct. For a distinct() call with
>   specified field names, the database will only compare the specified
>   field names.

Getting back to your ultimate goal of finding all conversation partners, I don't see a simple, elegant solution. One way to do it is to use aggregation:

```
receivers = user.sent_messages.values('recipient')
                .aggregate(num_messages=Count('id'))
senders = user.received_messages.values('sender')
              .aggregate(num_messages=Count('id'))
```

You'd then want to manually combine them if you don't care about the distinction between senders and receivers.